# Проксирование трафика с одного nginx на другой

Tags: nginx, minikube

Имею вот такую схему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сервере ubuntu-server 20.04
Вопрос такой, как лучше перенаправить трафик с открытых портов на хосте, на внутренний ip

пробовал такой конфиг

*ip адрес сервера 192.168.49.2 получен от minikube*

*proxy.conf*

```
stream {
    upstream ingress_server_secure {
        server 192.168.49.2:443;
    }
    upstream ingress_server_unsecure {
        server 192.168.49.2:80;
    }
    server {
        listen 443;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass ingress_server_secure;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        proxy_pass ingress_server_unsecure;
    }
}
```

*nginx.conf*

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/ingress.conf;

http {
    # стандартный конфиг
}
```

И это работало для service1.example.ru, но не работает service2.example.ru
service2 отваливается по timeout.
Заметил что

```
curl service1.example.ru --header "Host: service2.example.ru"
```

получает доступ к нужному сервису. DNS записи проверил, запись для service2.example.ru в наличии и создана давно

Вопрос такой: Почему такой вариант не работает? И как сделать это нормально? Потенциально есть необходимость добавить еще несколько кластеров, соответственно ip для них будет свой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае все оказалось банально, была запись в hosts
Убрав ее, все заработало

Конфиг из вопроса рабочий

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).